# Changing a rails datetime to string in Angular controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, datetime, coffeescript

I'm learning angular, and have attached one to a rails api. I'm rendering an object's date in my view with angular `{{example.date}}`. I'm assuming the best place to massage the JSON coming out of my rails api is in the angular controller, but having a hard time grasping how to do that. Here's my setup:

Rails controller:

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
    def index
      render json: Example.all
    end

    def show
      render json: Example.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Angular Service (coffeescript):

```
App.factory 'Example', ['$resource', ($resource)->
  $resource '/api/examples/:id', id: '@id'
]
```

Angular Controller (coffeescript):

```
App.controller 'ExampleCtrl', ['$scope', 'Example', ($scope, Example) ->
  $scope.example = Example.query()
]
```

All of this basic plumbing culminates to an `ng-repeat`in my haml view:

```
  %div{"ng-controller" => "ExampleCtrl"}
        %ul
          %li{"ng-repeat" => "example in example"}
            %h3 {{example.date}}
```

I believe my `Example.query()` in the angular controller is returning a large array of all the data. How would I write an each loop in coffeescript to transform all datetimes, such as `Tue, 23 Sep 2014 00:00:00 UTC +00:00`, to formatted dates? I have bower hooked up on my app and can install moment js if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried with ng-filter ? where we can modify our data using filters. You can even format the dates

Comment: That did the trick. Learning angular, and did not know about ng-filter. Beautiful, thank you!

Comment: Now it is filtering dates properly, but rounding down to the previous date. `2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` will now become `Dec 31, 2013`

Comment: can you post your expression you are trying with

Comment: `{{example.date | date:'longDate'}}` I assume this may have to do with the time being at `T00:00:00.000Z`. I am now trying to add 1 second to all of my records in rails console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use directive `ng-filter` to modify your outputs in the view. 
Filter work using pipe `|`.

**Example:**

```
{{1288323623006 | date:'medium'}}: Oct 28, 2010 11:40:23 PM
```

In this above example the

```
{{input | required_format }} = Formatted Output
```

You can go through below link for many formatting options for dates.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to update and let anyone else checking this out that I ended up going with a solution I feel is much cleaner.

Instead of trying to alter data in the view, I elected to define a method in my model, and then render the JSON through the method.

Model.rb:

```
    def format_date
      self.date.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
    end
```

Controller.rb

```
    def index
      render json: Run.where(:date => 1.month.ago..Date.today).order(date: :asc).as_json(include: [:salmon, :dam], :methods => [:format_date])
    end
```

Hope that helps!